# Proving that MLE is equal to LSE

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

Assuming that $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$

I want to prove that the maximum likelihood estimator is equal to the least squares estimator. Now, I think I'm very close to making the proof, I just need some guidance.

#### MLE approach:

$y_i = \beta_0 +  \beta  X_i + \epsilon$ is the linear regression model, and we can get that $\epsilon = y_i -  \beta_0 - \beta X_i $, and we assume that $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

Because we assume normality, we can get the density function, like this:

$$ f(X_i | \beta, \sigma^2) = (1 / 2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2} e^{-(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta X_i)^2) / 2\sigma^2} $$

Now write the likelihood function:

$$ L =  \prod_{i=0}^{n} = (1 / 2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2} e^{-(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta X_i)^2) / 2\sigma^2}$$

Take the log of the likelihood function:

$$ log L = n log (1/2\pi\sigma^2) - 1/2\sigma^2 \sum_{i=0}^{n}(Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_iX_i)^2)$$

Now take the derivative:

$$∂ / ∂\beta = 2/2\sigma^2 \sum X_i (Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta X_i) = 0$$

And this is the final derivative that I got...

#### LSE approach:

I successfully found that the estimator for the least squares $\hat{\beta}$ and that is just the normal equation:

$$\hat{\beta} = (X^t X)^{-1}  * X^ty $$

Now how do I connect both approaches? what should I add to actually show these two are exactly the same estimator? I feel I did the hard part, but I'm missing the final touch.

Thanks all!

Comment: It's a multiparameter likelihood, your score function is equal in dimension to the parameter vector - one for $\beta_0$, one for $\beta_1$ and one for $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 2):

> Take the log of the likelihood function:
>
> $$ log L = n log (1/2\pi\sigma^2) - 1/2\sigma^2 \color{red}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}(Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_iX_i)^2}$$

Wait a sec, don't you have the sum of squared residuals here?

Comment: Yeah, this is basically $\epsilon^2$, but how does this help me? I'm just no getting it. What does it mean that the $\epsilon^2$ appears in the $log L$ function ?

Comment: @CORy In your derivation of the log likelihood, you see that the log likelihood (for Gaussian distributed error terms) is the same as minus the sum of squares (along with some other terms but they do not depend on the $\beta$'s). So, maximizing the log likelihood, is equivalent to minimizing the sum of squared errors (which is the least squares method).

Comment: Maybe you are pondering about something else, which is why the LSE approach results in the formula $\hat{\beta} = (X^t X)^{-1}  * X^ty$ (which relates to perpendicular projection)?

Comment: I got it now, very tricky question.. thank you!!